# How to write factory pattern staking pool solana program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, rust, staking

My goal is to let users to create staking pools where people can stake SOL and earn reward tokens, so simply put something like staking pool factory smart contract on Ethereum.

As far as I figured I'm not redeploying programs for each users, instead create a 'config' account for each user and somehow bind it to the program and the user

I managed to created a config account each time pool creator initializes a pool, but failed to let the user to create multiple pools(pool config accounts).

basically I thought I could manage this to pass some seeds when looking for a PDA, but I'm not sure what I should use beside the pool creator's wallet address,

right now I used some hard coded index to let the same user to create another pool, but I beleive there would be more proper solution

this is program rust code basically look like atm

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{ self, Mint, TokenAccount, Transfer };

use crate::state::*;

pub fn handler(
    ctx: Context<InitializePool>,
    pool_id: String,
    pool_fee: u8,
    initial_funding: u64,
    reward_rate: u8,
    start_slot: u64,
    end_slot: u64
) -> Result<()> {
    let pool_config = &mut ctx.accounts.pool_config;
    pool_config.owner = ctx.accounts.creator.key();
    pool_config.pool_id = pool_id;
    pool_config.pool_fee = pool_fee;
    pool_config.start_slot = start_slot;
    pool_config.end_slot = end_slot;
    pool_config.reward_rate = reward_rate;

    pool_config.stake_mint = ctx.accounts.stake_mint.key();
    pool_config.reward_mint = ctx.accounts.reward_mint.key();
    pool_config.pool_reward_token_vault = ctx.accounts.pool_reward_token_vault.key();
    pool_config.pool_stake_token_vault = ctx.accounts.pool_stake_token_vault.key();
    pool_config.state_addr = ctx.accounts.pool_state.key();

    // Transfer Token from creator to pool account
    token::transfer(ctx.accounts.transfer_reward_to_pool_context(), initial_funding)?;

    let pool_state = &mut ctx.accounts.pool_state;
    pool_state.reward_amount = initial_funding;
    pool_state.total_staked = 0;

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(pool_id: String)]
pub struct InitializePool<'info> {
    #[account(
        // init_if_needed,
        init,
        payer = creator,
        space = 500,
        seeds = [pool_id.as_bytes().as_ref(), creator.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub pool_config: Account<'info, PoolConfig>,

    #[account(init, payer = creator, space = 100)]
    pub pool_state: Account<'info, PoolState>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,

    pub stake_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    pub reward_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub pool_stake_token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub pool_reward_token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator_reward_token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, token::Token>,
}

impl<'info> InitializePool<'info> {
    fn transfer_reward_to_pool_context(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Transfer<'info>> {
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: self.creator_reward_token_vault.to_account_info(),
            to: self.pool_reward_token_vault.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.creator.to_account_info(),
        };
        CpiContext::new(self.token_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts)
    }
}
```

and the test code

```
  async function init_pool(poolId: string, startSlot: BN, endSlot: BN, initialFunding, rewardRate, poolFee) {
    // Create staker wallet and airdrop    
    const creator = await createRandomWalletAndAirdrop(provider, 2)
    // Create a new mint for mock stake token
    const stakeMint = await createRandomMint(provider, 6)
    // Create a new mint for mock reward token
    const rewardMint = await createRandomMint(provider, 6)

    // Create a reward token account for the pool creator
    const creatorRewardTokenVault = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      provider.connection,
      admin.payer,
      rewardMint,
      creator.publicKey
    );

    // Mint some mock reward token to the pool creator's account
    await mintTo(
      provider.connection,
      admin.payer,
      rewardMint,
      creatorRewardTokenVault.address,
      admin.publicKey,
      BigInt(initialFunding)
    );

    // Create a reward token account for the pool creator
    const poolRewardTokenVault = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      provider.connection,
      admin.payer,
      rewardMint,
      program.programId
    );

    // Create a token account for the pool to receive staked token
    const poolStakeTokenVault = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      provider.connection,
      admin.payer,
      stakeMint,
      program.programId
    );

    // Fetch the PDA of pool config account
    const [POOL_CONFIG_PDA] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from(poolId), creator.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );

    console.log(`Pool PDA: ${POOL_CONFIG_PDA.toString()}`);

    // Pool State Account
    const poolStateAccount = web3.Keypair.generate();

    const tx = await program.methods
      .initializePool(
        poolId,
        poolFee,
        initialFunding,
        rewardRate,
        startSlot,
        endSlot
      )
      .accounts({
        poolState: poolStateAccount.publicKey,
        poolConfig: POOL_CONFIG_PDA,
        creator: creator.publicKey,
        stakeMint: stakeMint,
        rewardMint: rewardMint,
        poolStakeTokenVault: poolStakeTokenVault.address,
        creatorRewardTokenVault: creatorRewardTokenVault.address,
        poolRewardTokenVault: poolRewardTokenVault.address,
        systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .signers([creator, poolStateAccount])
      .rpc();

    console.log(`Pool Init Transaction: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${tx}?cluster=devnet`);

    return {
      POOL_CONFIG_PDA,
      stakeMint,
      rewardMint,
      creatorRewardTokenVault,
      poolRewardTokenVault,
      poolStakeTokenVault,
      poolStateAccount,
      initialFunding
    };
  }

  it("create pool_config account", async () => {
    const start_slot = new BN(1);
    const end_slot = new BN(1e10);
    const initialFunding = new BN(9000000); // 99 tokens of mock reward with 6 decimals
    const rewardRate = new BN(10);
    const poolFee = 5;

    const res = await init_pool("0", start_slot, end_slot, initialFunding, rewardRate, poolFee);

    // Fetch the pool config account and log results
    const pool_config = await program.account.poolConfig.fetch(res.POOL_CONFIG_PDA);

    console.log(`pool owner: `, pool_config.owner.toString());
    console.log(`pool id: `, pool_config.poolId);
    console.log(`pool fee: `, pool_config.poolFee);
    console.log(`pool start_slot: `, pool_config.startSlot);
    console.log(`pool end_slot: `, pool_config.endSlot);
    console.log(`pool reward rate: `, pool_config.rewardRate);
    console.log(`pool stakeMint: `, pool_config.stakeMint.toString());
    console.log(`pool rewardMint: `, pool_config.rewardMint.toString());
    console.log(`pool poolStakeTokenVault: `, pool_config.poolStakeTokenVault.toString());
    console.log(`pool poolRewardTokenVault: `, pool_config.poolRewardTokenVault.toString());

    // Assert initial funding transfer
    const creatorRewardInfo = await provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(res.creatorRewardTokenVault.address)
    assert.equal(
      creatorRewardInfo.value.amount.toString(),
      '0',
      "The creator reward token account should be empty"
    );

    const poolInitialInfo = await provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(res.poolRewardTokenVault.address)
    assert.equal(
      poolInitialInfo.value.amount.toString(),
      initialFunding.toString(),
      "The pool reward token account should match the initial funding amount"
    );
    // Fetch the pool state account and assert results
    const pool_state = await program.account.poolState.fetch(pool_config.stateAddr)

    assert.equal(
      pool_state.rewardAmount.toString(),
      initialFunding.toString(),
      "The pool state for initial funding is not set correctly."
    );
  });

  it("create another pool_config account and read all", async () => {
    const start_slot = new BN(1);
    const end_slot = new BN(1e10);
    const initialFunding = new BN(11000000); // 11 tokens of mock reward with 6 decimals
    const rewardRate = (22);
    const poolFee = 10;

    await init_pool("1", start_slot, end_slot, initialFunding, rewardRate, poolFee);

    const pools = await program.account.poolConfig.all();

    pools.forEach((pool, index) => {
      console.log(`pool pda: `, pool.publicKey.toString());
      console.log(`pool owner: `, pool.account.owner.toString());
      console.log(`pool id: `, pool.account.poolId);
    });
  });
```

and here the [link](https://github.com/dxtn89/solana_staking_pool_deployer) to my project so far.

I'd appreciate any advice on this problem and, if someone can tell me if I'm on the right track.

And also would welcome any advice with the current codebase with any improvement or fixes.

Comment: solblaze is a popular liquid staking program and it appears their program is OSS
`https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/stake-pool/program`

Comment: thank you for the comment, @Hyetigran, although I could not find open source in Solblaze, btw, I edited the post with my recent findings

Comment: https://spl.solana.com/stake-pool/quickstart

Answer (score 3):

The SPL stake pool does not have configuration knobs per user, opting instead to use a fungible token to represent fractional ownership in the pool.

If you need more configuration than that, you'll need to modify the smart contract to suit your needs and deploy it yourself.

If you want to use the existing implementation, you can use the `spl-stake-pool-cli` https://crates.io/crates/spl-stake-pool-cli. The docs contain instructions on how to use every command at https://spl.solana.com/stake-pool/overview, but you can get started with:

```
$ spl-stake-pool create-pool --epoch-fee-numerator 3 --epoch-fee-denominator 1000 \
  --withdrawal-fee-numerator 3 --withdrawal-fee-denominator 1000 \
  --deposit-fee-numerator 3 --deposit-fee-denominator 1000 \
  --referral-fee 50 --max-validators 2350
```

Comment: thank you for the reply although I think it's a bit out of topic,I edit the post for clarification.